# Are villager price increases due to killing them temporary?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I killed a villager, at the time I didn't know that it would cause the other villager's trade to increase by so much... and I was wondering how long they would keep it high? or if its a permanent thing?

I'm on Java 1.14.3.

Is there any other way to lower their prices other than defeating a raid?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Villagers use gossip to determine prices

Hitting Villagers or a villages Iron Golem creates `minor_negative` gossip and killing villagers or a villages Iron Golem creates `major_negative` gossip, raising prices.

Curing Zombie Villagers creates `major_positive` gossip and buying from the last trade slot creates `trade` and `minor_positive` gossip, Lowering prices.

Completing raids will lower prices for a certain amount of time and the villagers will give you gifts depending on their profession. (https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hero_of_the_Village#Gifts)

Prices will stay raised / lowered until you do something good / bad

Comment: I think 1.14.4 is changing this behavior, though. Price changes won't be permanent anymore.